# git flow feature finish

Tags: git-flow

Hi I am new and I am not sure if this is a valid question or if the answer is  a simple "it's the same"

I am using git flow for my java project and I have been using

`$ git flow feature start someFeature`

and usualy to end my feature I used:

`$ git flow finish someFeature`

My friends now told me that git flow uses:

`$ git flow feature finish someFeature`

to finish the feature, now my question. What is the difference? if so are there any benefits to using `feature finish` ?

Like I said I have only been using Git for about 2 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just played around with the `git flow` commands and noticed the following:

1. `git flow finish`: finish the branch you currently have checked out, if it's a "finish-able" branch. For example, if you have a feature branch checked out, it will finish the currently checked out feature branch. This also works to complete a release branch if you currently have a release branch checked out. I assume it works for hotfix branches as well.
2. `git flow feature finish`: finish the branch you currently have checked out, if it's a feature branch. This will fail if you don't currently have a feature branch checked out.
3. `git flow finish f2` If you currently have a feature branch checked out, then it is the same as if you typed: `git flow feature finish f2`. If you currently have a release branch checked out, then it will act as if you typed: `git flow release finish f2`. In that case, if `f2` is a feature branch, it will fail.
4. `git flow feature finish f2`: Regardless of what branch you have checked out, finish `f2` if it is a feature branch.

Using the full syntax has the advantage that it doesn't matter what branch you have checked out when you do it, and you're less likely to accidentally complete the wrong branch. But you can certainly save some keystrokes if you know you want to finish your currently checked out branch, or even another feature branch while working on a feature (perhaps so you can rebase the current feature onto the latest `develop` afterwards to use that other feature.)

**Side Note:** I played around with the `git flow` commands years ago, but it was short lived as I quickly came to the conclusion that I preferred to do the merges myself. This is especially true if you are using a remote repo, in which case `develop` and `master` are probably protected branches requiring PRs. Also, using `origin/develop` is typically easier than trying to keep your local `develop` up to date all the time.

Comment: To the DVer: I'd appreciate some context here as to what's wrong with the answer, or how it could be improved...